# how can i combine two 2d lists of same index length?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I am pretty new to python, and I have a little problem.

I need to combine two 2D lists like this:

```
list1= [['a','b','c'],['d','e']]
list2= [[1,2,3],[4,5]]
```

result should be like this:

```
result= [['a1','b2','c3'],['d4','e5']]
```

Comment: Are these strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use *nested list comprehension* with two `zip(..)`s:

```
[ [ '%s%s'%zi for zi in zip(*z) ] for z in zip(list1,list2) ]
```

This will generate:

```
>>> list1= [['a','b','c'],['d','e']]
>>> list2= [[1,2,3],[4,5]]
>>> [ [ '%s%s'%zi for zi in zip(*z) ] for z in zip(list1,list2) ]
[['a1', 'b2', 'c3'], ['d4', 'e5']]
```

The outer loop thus iterates over the two lists `list1` and `list2` in parallel and constructs tuples we assign to `z`. For each of these tuples, we perform a second `zip` call `zip(*z)` to construct tuples of the two subelements. For each of these subelements, we then contruct a string with `'%s%s'%zi`.

Or you can cast it explicitly to a string, like:

```
[ [ ''.join(map(str,zi)) for zi in zip(*z) ] for z in zip(list1,list2) ]
```

Comment: `[ [ ''.join(zi) for zi in zip(*z) ] for z in zip(list1, map(str, list2)) ]` makes the type conversion explicit

Comment: @f5r5e5d: I that case you have to do the `map`ping one level deeper. Now you are going to stringify the sublists of `list2`.

Comment: opps, `[ [ ''.join((zi[0],str(zi[1]))) for zi in zip(*z) ] for z in zip(list1,list2) ]` was working, took the failed `map()` try by mistake

Comment: `[[''.join(zi) for zi in zip(*z) ] for z in zip(list1, [map(str, i) for i in list2])]` fixed the `map(str, )`